# How to send notifications depending on the Firebase data using Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app where people sign up for events and I want the app to notify the users registered for and event the day before it happens. All the data is stored in Firebase. So basically I would like to know how do I make my app read from Firebase the data from all the users in a regular basis and if a user is signed up for an event and the date is close send him a notification, without the admin having to do anything or using the console. Thanks

Comment: So, just so we're clear, you're looking for recommendations for your server side solution for sending the pushes, as opposed to overall setting up a broadcast receiver in your application, correct?

Comment: Well, im a beginner at using data bases and Firebase. All I have been able to do is store all the information of all the users in the Firebase Database. Now i have to make my Android app notify users when an event is close and I have no clue how to set it up. And all the Firebase Cloud Messaging tutorials I have seen send the notifications manually from the console, not automatically depending on the date. Im not asking for a complete tutorial step by step of course, but would appreciate to know what do I have to use to make my app send notifications like these

Comment: You can use background services for detection and notifications.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make this process automatic You can write Firebase cloud functions and can add triggers on nodes to execute cloud function, In that cloud function you can send push notifications using FCM depending upon your requirements. here are the helping links

[Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions)

[Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)

Otherwise if want to avoid cloud functions you can directly send message from App to App using FCM without involving server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to keep all of your server side logic running off of Firebase, the Firebase Cloud Functions are what you're looking for.

Here is the documentation for setting up functions to be run on a schedule: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

If you're not looking to run your service from the Google Cloud, then the next best option is to setup [CRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) jobs if you're using a Unix based system, or the [Task Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page) if you're running a Windows based system.